# java mail CC and BCC not working

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am using javax.mail to send some emails.
It works fine, except that it doesn't send the message to CC/BCC

```
message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("a@x.com"));
message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress("b@x.com"));
```

a@x.com correctly recieves the message (where it's also indicated the CC address), but b@x.com doens't recieve it

Here the complete code:

```
        // Get system properties
        Properties props = System.getProperties();

        // Setup mail server
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "192.168.1.1");
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        // Crea un authenticator (per mandare mail anche all'esterno del dominio)
        Authenticator authenticator = new Interfaccia_CSR.SMTPAuthenticator();

        // Get session
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, authenticator);

        // Define message
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("sender@x.com"));

        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("a@x.com"));
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress("b@x.com"));

        message.setSubject(oggetto);

        // create the message part 
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        //fill message
        messageBodyPart.setText(testo);

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // Put parts in message
        message.setContent(multipart);

        // Send the message
        Transport.send(message, message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: here? Transport.send(message, message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Transport.send(message, message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
```

You're only sending it to the recipients in the `To:` field this way.

See the difference between [`Transport.send(Message)` and `Transport.send(Message, Address[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/mail/Transport.html#send%28javax.mail.Message%29):

> - `send(Message msg)`: [...] The message will be sent to all recipient addresses specified in the message (as returned from the Message
>     method getAllRecipients), using message transports appropriate to each
>     address.
> - `send(Message msg, Address[] addresses)`: [...] Send the message to the specified addresses, ignoring any recipients specified in the message
>     itself.

Comment: damn it was so easy and i am so blind =)   Thanks

Comment: @Maik: Do you have solution for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29392185/unable-to-read-bcc-field-of-sent-mails-in-java/29398710#29398710

Answer (score 4):

try just

```
Transport.send(message);
```

instead