# Unable to read BCC field of sent mails in java

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am facing one problem while extracting BCC address from incoming mail.
Here is the sample code that is used.

```
 public EmailVO dumpEnvelope(Message m) throws Exception {
             EmailVO emailVO = new EmailVO();
        if ((addresses = m.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC)) != null) {
            emailVO.setBcc(this.getAddresses(addresses, "BCC"));
        }
}
```

I am getting null value in BCC.
While debugging I found BCC recipient's name in header field but I am not able to access that header.
Is this code issue or there is some specific setting while sending mail like not to include BCC fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your Message object which contains all the details about the mails.
As the BCC is the part of mail but also it will be hidden, but as per my knowledge you can retrieve the information from your mail headers.

```
Address[] addresses = m.getHeader("Your Header Name HERE");
```

This will give you all the details regarding your particular header tag in mails.

**for e.g.**

```
Address[] addresses = m.getHeader("Delivered-To");
```

This tag will give you all the information about the recipients of the mail, which will also include BCC.

you can also add your custom headers for mail.

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of Bcc is that it's a **blind** carbon copy - the recipients don't get to see who was copied.  You won't see Bcc fields in messages you receive.  (Sometimes a Bcc'ed recipient will see the Bcc header in the messages they receive, but the other recipients will get a copy of the message without the Bcc.  But I don't think many mailers do that anymore because it requires sending two different versions of the message.)

Answer (score 0):

```
addresses = m.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC);
```

returns an array of addresses. You can check the content in a for loop:

```
Address[] addresses = m.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC);
for(Address address : addresses){
    System.out.println(address);
}
```

Comment: I have used the same but I am getting NULL in addresses.